# trying to understand some java concepts

Tags: java, oop

This is probably a silly questions but its something I am trying to understand.  I have 2 classes: a Person class and an Account class.  In the Account class I have a 3 methods to set an account balance, to withdraw from that balance, and to return that balance.  If I created a new object for a new Person and a new Account how do I tie them together? By together I mean how do I know when I try and get the the account balance, that I am getting it for a specific person and not just anyones balance? (assuming I have multiple account and person objects).

Comment: What are the *properties* of your `Account` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You connect them together by placing the `Account` (Wouldn't be a mistake to make it a `Array` of `Account`s) object into the `Person` object. and then access the appropriate account using the `Person`:

```
class Person
{
   String name;
   String id;
   ...
   List<Account> ownedAccounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
}
```

Comment: And if a Person owns several Accounts?

Comment: I think, the reverse is more compliant. Account objects should refer to Person

Comment: And for married people with a joined account?

Comment: @Aubin Married couples would simply share the same Account object in their respective `ownedAccounts` lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can add field in Person class for instance:

```
ArrayList<Account> accounts;
```

or you can add some field in Account class (if only one person can be owner otherwise you will also need some list or set):

```
Person person;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that makes sense to me is to have an account object reference in the Person class.

```
class Person { Account account; }
```

and then you can add a checkAccount method to the person class.

```
void checkBalance(){ return account.getBalance(); }
```

Then wherever you have a Person object you can call

```
person.checkBalance();
```

To make sure that the account is that person's you should pass the Account object in the constructor of the Person object.

```
Person(Account account){ this.account = account }
```

Or you could have a setter method. If every person in the system must have an account then passing it in the constructor is a better idea.

Comment: And if a Person owns several Accounts?

Comment: The question doesn't specify that. But if it did using a List<Account> and having an addAccount() method would make sense